# angular ui router not working / routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this project structure :

```
-root
|-JS
  |-app.js
  |-COMPONENTS
   |-HOME
    |-homeController.js
    |-homeView.html
   |-ERROR
    |-error.html
|-index.html
```

Here is index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- JS LOADING -->
<script src="./bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!--APP JS -->
<script src="js/components/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/shared/services/lb-service.js"></script>

<!--HOME JS-->
<script src="./js/components/home/homeController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='benirius'>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="error">Error</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and app.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('benirius', [
    'lbServices',
    'ui.router'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/components/home/homeView.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .state('error', {
                url: '/error',
                templateUrl: '/components/error/error.html'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }]);
```

edit adding homeController.js:

```
angular.module('benirius',[])
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Inside home.";
}]);
```

Angular ui router does not create links / load pages.
All js files are loaded and no javascript error shown in console.
Does someone know why ui-router is not working ?

Ps : I've been playing around with templateUrl path with no success.

Comment: template paths shown don't match directory structure shown

Comment: As mentioned I tried : "js/components/home/homeView.html", "components/home/homeView.html" but nothing changed.
What path do you suggest ?

Comment: Please post the contents of homeController.js

Comment: homeController added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As show [here in angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr), when you separate files and add controllers, services, or others to a module, you have to load it with no arguments.
You first define your app in a file :

```
angular.module('benirius', [
    'lbServices',
    'ui.router'
])
.config(
  // CODE IN HERE
);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    }]);
```

Then if you want to add elements to your app in another file, you load the module with no arguments, like this:

```
// notice there is no second argument therefore it loads the previously defined module 'benirius'
angular.module('benirius') 
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Inside home.";
}]);

//=> NO ERROR
```

instead of:

```
// In this case, it is considered as a redefinition of 'benirius' module with no dependencies injected
angular.module('benirius',[])
.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "Inside home.";
}]);

//=> ERROR
```